# Oracle Pro*C equivalent for ODBC SQLRowCount

Tags: c++, oracle, proc

I'm looking for a way to obtain the number of affected rows after executing an EXEC SQL EXECUTE (DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT) statement.
AFAIKS there is no way to do this with GET DESCRIPTOR?

Thanks,
Marko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really searched the net half a day for this and just a minute after posting the question here I apparently hit the right search phrase that revealed that `sqlca.sqlerrd[2]` contains the number of affected rows of the last executed statement.

Answer (score 4):

sqlca.sqlerrd[2] contains the number of affected rows of the last executed statement .
it returns the number of rows which were effected by earlier statement 
you can check the following statement

if(sqlca.sqlerrd[2]==0)
printf("No rows returned ");
else 
printf("no of rows %d",sqlca.sqlerrd[2]);